# Neo4j backup finds inconsistencies. Now what?

Tags: neo4j

The `neo4j-backup` reports some inconsistencies with my database.

```
2015-04-22 19:27:44.175+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
    Number of errors: 4
    Number of warnings: 0
    Number of inconsistent PROPERTY records: 1
    Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP_GROUP records: 3
}
```

I was able to step around it this time by restoring a backup made immediately before the problem occurred, but what would my options be if that was not possible?

Using Neo4j 2.2.0 here.

Comment: Good question. I had this problem a few months ago and ended up rebuilding my database.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a commercial enterprise subscription this could be handled as part of Neo Technology's support.

Another option is using Michael's storecopy tool to copy over your database, see https://github.com/jexp/store-utils.

Comment: I saw someone else mention Michael's storecopy, too. Is that considered The Solution to this issue outside of contacting support?